# Hours not coming through when using LocalDate in Java

Tags: java, java-time

I'm trying to format today's date to be "MM/dd/yyy HH:00" where the minutes are always zeroed out. The hours aren't coming through properly when using this format:

```
LocalDate date = DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")).toLocalDate();
String format = date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:00");

logger.info(format);
```

**Output**

[image]

Is there a different way to grab hours using `LocalDate`?

Comment: `LocalDate` doesn't store hours, just year, month of year and day of month. Maybe you want `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: @AndyTurner that was it! thank you much

Comment: You seem to use JodaTime (see class `DateTimeZone`) not `java.time` as your tag suggests. But of course, the Joda-version does not store clock time, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the JavaDoc for [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

> A date without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03.

and:

> This class does not store or represent a time or time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

Use [LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instead.

Comment: Good point, but `LocalDateTime` loses information about time zone. Instead, `ZonedDateTime` is appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )
         .truncatedTo( java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS )
         .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm" , Locale.US ) )
```

> 02/27/2017 23:00

## Details

The [Answer by rmuller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36434583/642706) is correct.

## java.time vs Joda-Time

A bigger problem: You seem to be using [`Joda-Time`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) classes but labeled your question with `java-time` meaning the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

[Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491410/meno-hochschild) commented on the Question pointing out this apparent confusion of libraries.

The Joda-Time project is a separate library, not built into Java. This project provided the inspiration and experience for java.time. While similar in concepts, java.time is entirely re-engineered, not at all a drop-in replacement. Both Joda-Time and java.time are led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne (“jodastephen”)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen). The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

There are no `DateTime` or `DateTimeZone` classes in java.time.

## Using java.time

In java.time, you code would be like this.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

But you want a time-of-day, and as [rmuller pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36434583/642706), you need to use another class as `LocalDate` is date-only without any time-of-day. Instead use [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to get the date and the time-of-day as seen through a particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) determined by a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

## Misuse of formatting pattern

Another problem: Hard-coding the formatting pattern to show zeros in place of minute-of-hour is a tricky way to accomplish your goal. Doing so does not make your intentions clear. Other programmers reading your code may miss your maneuver.

I find code to be more maintainable if it “tells the truth”. So rather than “lie” by altering the display of the minutes with hard-coded zero digits, it is better to alter the underlying data itself. Benefits include making your intentions clear, and making values seen in the debugger match the output of your strings.

### `truncatedTo`

I suggest you instead alter the value of your date-time object explicitly. Call the [`truncatedTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method to lop off the minutes and seconds and fractional second. Those lopped-off values become zero.

The java.time use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So rather than change the values (“mutate”) of an object, we generate a fresh object with values based on those of the original object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTruncatedToHour = zdt.truncatedTo( java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ;
```

> zdtTruncatedToHour.toString(): 2017-02-27T23:00-05:00[America/New_York]

From there, you can use the usual `toString` or [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) ways to generate a string, with only zeros appearing in the minutes, seconds, and fractional second.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm" , Locale.US );
String output = zdtTruncatedToHour.format( f );
```

> 02/27/2017 23:00

See this example [code running live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/02hcOf).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).